# How to rewrite all the current page with Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have created a simple page with a button on the center.

Now I want that when I click the button then the current page is completly rewritten with new HTML and Javascript code loaded from the server.

How can I do this with ajax ?

Comment: are you using any javascript-library? jQuery for instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nick is right with what he says, but if there's no other way:

```
$('a').click(function() {
  $('body').load("test.html");
});
```

**EDIT**: <strike>Making sure `load` only fetches content inside the `<body>` Tag from the remote adress.</strike> For me it didn't work to fetch only the `<body>` tag by defining `body` => `load('test.html body')`

---

To animate the page you could do something like this:

```
$('a').click(function() {
  $('body').load("test.html", function() {
    $(this).hide().fadeIn(2000);
  });
});
```

but then I suggest to implement at least one wrapper-element.

Comment: This would load (or attempt to) the entire `<html>` element into the body :)

Comment: as far as i know, `load` grab's only everything inside the `<body>` tag. I might be wrong

Comment: kinda, it's more the browser that does the stripping down, so this will vary, that's the "attempt to" part :)

Answer (score 4):

Suggestion: post with a normal form and reload the page.  If you're reloading the entire page anyway, you're doing away with all the benefits of AJAX anyway, best to reload the entire page, for example:

```
<form action="otherpagr.html">
  <input type="submit" value="Click me" />
</form>
```

AJAX is for replacing *part* of a page to reduce the overhead...but if you're replacing say the entire `<body>` it's easier to just load the page you're going to.

Comment: you right but I need to do some animation with javascript when I reload the page :)

Comment: @xRobot - you can do that in a JavaScript block right in the page, using XmlHttpRequest for this is a bit overkill IMO (and a less pleasant experience for your users...especially with older browsers).

Comment: +1. You can spend a long time coming up with clever transition code, catering for open-in-new-window, and using hash-navigation history and `#!` to make it so that navigation still actually works... or just do it the normal way the rest of the web works and get the usability and accessibility stuff for free.